# links relative to website root with IIS virtual directory

Tags: php, html, iis, windows-server-2003-r2

I have a website at `http://myserver/project1`.

'myserver' is a Windows Server 2003 server with IIS6.

'project1' is a virtual directory (the physical path of which is `C:\myprojects\project1`.

I have read that the best way to link to an external stylesheet (for example) is to use a forward slash, e.g. `<link href="/style.css">`, as I would also like to link to this stylesheet from a subfolder of the virtual directory.

I would expect this to look for the css file in `http://myserver/project1/`, but it seems to be looking in `http://myserver/`. I know this because typing `<link href="/project1/style.css">` works.

I am guessing it's normal for `http://myserver/` to be considered the 'website root' as this is the 'Default Website' (in IIS terms). What I would like to know is if there a way to (either via IIS or PHP) to change this so that I can write paths in the format `/style.css` and have the virtual directory find them.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you, on non Windows systems I think I would approach this with a [symbolic link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/symlink.7.html) or simply checking out the common directories for each domain.  You can't use a relative link path like you show to include across a domain.  File system path vs your server URI is apples and oranges.  Maybe take a look at [Mklink](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194.aspx).  This [post](http://gunnalag.com/2012/03/28/iis-supports-folder-redirection-via-symlink-or-shortcut-mechanism/) might also be helpful.

Now more I think about this doesn't IIS6 just provide a simple way in the GUI to add (maybe they call them virtual directories?) multiple folders into the domain.  This SO post might be pretty close to your question: [How do I resolve absolute URLs for different sites in the same parent IIS virtual directory in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488298/how-do-i-resolve-absolute-urls-for-different-sites-in-the-same-parent-iis-virtua)

Comment: Yes, I am using a Virtual Directory. The issue is that the browser doesn't see the virtual directory as the root of the site when looking for files/folders.